# How to "fetch" nested models and collections using backbone.js

Tags: ajax, nested, backbone.js

I have a model which has 2 nested collections.  What's the best way of automatically fetching those collections when I "fetch" the parent model?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you can include the dependant objects in your JSON. I do not know the backend you are using, but this would save you a couple round trips:

```
{
  att1: val,
  col1: [{obj1: val}, {...}],
  col2: [{...}]
}
```

Otherwise, override the initialize of Model to create and fetch the 2 new dependent collections.

Comment: No, I don't want to bootstrap data rendered inside the page.  I'm looking for a purely client side solution to the problem.

Comment: No bootstrap needed. When you fetch the data you can have your backend return whatever including the dependent objects